# Remote-Desktop-Connection using GPU

Tags: windows-7, linux, remote-desktop, gpu, vnc

i have to edit a video. The only problem is, that my editing program doesn't work on linux (HitFilm). Now I have another workstation running Windows. So I want to use this workstation to run, while I am running a remote Desktop on it from my linux PC. So far so good. This works. Now, the problem is, that the program needs at least 512 MB VRAM to start (the GPU has 1GB). When I start the program, it starts properly, but when I log onto the rdektop remote desktop connection, it won't start anymore. It says my system doesn't match the requirements. So i think it isn't using the GPU anymore...

Is there a way to let me use the GPU even when I am on a remote desktop connection from linux to windows?

PS:I've tried VNC, but it was way too slow to work. It was too laggy even if the Workstation is right next to me in the network.

Thanks. Jukisu.

Comment: Have you tried ScreenConnect or Teamviewer?

Comment: Yes, I have tried Teamviewer, but the quality is very bad, and the fact that i only have a 4:3 lcd left (i am working on a laptop) -> the ratio of the viewed screen is only 4:3 too. That isn't a problem in remote desktop connection.
I also tried ScreenConnect, but assuming that it is working over initernet, in dont think it is too fast. Also I cant get it to work on linux...